# "Exited sync due to fetch errors" while fetching B2G code

Tags: build, mozilla, firefox-os, gecko, b2g

I am trying to prepare my first B2G build for my Intex Cloud FX phone using [these steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Preparing_for_your_first_B2G_build). I found out that my phone's code is *tarako* from the [Firefox OS Phones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Phone_specs) page. However, running `./config.sh tarako` fails every time.

Although the above article does say the following:

> **Note**: it is possible for config.sh to fail with git-related fetching
>   errors such as the following :
>
> Fetching projects:  95% (118/124) error: Exited sync due to fetch
>   errors
>
> This appears to be caused by a connection error on the Android repo
>   source repository. In this case, you will want to rerun config.sh.
>   After a short while, It will automatically resume where it left off.
>   You might have do to this several times until it finally fetches all
>   projects.

But, I've tried it several times and the process aborts with the same error every time. 
Here's the log:

```
Get https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/b2g-manifest
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring.
remote: Counting objects: 1725, done.
remote: Total 1725 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1725/1725), 708.93 KiB | 62.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1019/1019), done.
From https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/b2g-manifest
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      revert-203-bug1025788-v2 -> origin/revert-203-bug1025788-v2
 * [new branch]      v1-train   -> origin/v1-train
 * [new branch]      v1.0.0     -> origin/v1.0.0
 * [new branch]      v1.0.1     -> origin/v1.0.1
 * [new branch]      v1.1.0hd   -> origin/v1.1.0hd
 * [new branch]      v1.2       -> origin/v1.2
 * [new branch]      v1.2f      -> origin/v1.2f
 * [new branch]      v1.3       -> origin/v1.3
 * [new branch]      v1.3t      -> origin/v1.3t
 * [new branch]      v1.4       -> origin/v1.4
 * [new branch]      v2.0       -> origin/v2.0
 * [new branch]      v2.1       -> origin/v2.1
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_0_1_20130213094222 -> B2G_1_0_1_20130213094222
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315 -> B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315
 * [new tag]         B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315_BASE -> B2G_1_1_0_hd_20130530182315_BASE
 * [new tag]         closing-nightly -> closing-nightly

Your identity is: John Bupit
If you want to change this, please re-run 'repo init' with --config-name

repo has been initialized in /home/jbupit/b2g/B2G
Fetching project gecko.git
Fetching project moztt
Fetching project platform/hardware/libhardware
Fetching project platform/system/bluetooth
Fetching projects:   1% (1/84)  Fetching project platform/external/safe-iop
Fetching projects:   2% (2/84)  Fetching project platform/abi/cpp
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/system/bluetooth/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/hardware/libhardware/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/abi/cpp/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/external/safe-iop/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/abi/cpp/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/system/bluetooth/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/external/safe-iop/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
fatal: unable to access 'http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/hardware/libhardware/': Failed connect to sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085; Connection timed out
error: Cannot fetch platform/system/bluetooth
Fetching project gonk-misc
Fetching projects:   3% (3/84)  error: Cannot fetch platform/external/safe-iop
error: Cannot fetch platform/abi/cpp
error: Cannot fetch platform/hardware/libhardware

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
Repo sync failed
```

What should I do? Is there another way of downloading the code?

Comment: Either the spreadtrum server is down, or your network doesn't allow connections to spreadtrum. FYI, I can access http://sprdsource.spreadtrum.com:8085/b2g/android/platform/hardware/libhardware/ fine, can you? Maybe try over a VPN.

Also I doubt whether you can flash the Intex phone as it's not rooted by default.

Comment: No I can't. The connection times out every time.

Comment: Can you try it over a VPN connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into this - the server seems to be very unstable, or missing content at times

You may be able to piece together what you need from https://git.mozilla.org/?a=project_list&s=sprd&btnS=Search

You will need to edit the manifest XML with new URLs and change config.sh to use that.

The original sync was discussed in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=982360 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1014102